# What does an eigenvalue tell us about the system?

Tags: control-system

I have an electrical system to be controlled (Cuk converter). So I get the space-state model given by:
$$
\dot{x}(t)=Ax(t)+Bu(t)
$$

If I determine the eigenvalues (of the matrix A) I obtain: $${-113.654 + 482.816 j, -113.654 - 482.816 j, -85.204 + 
  174.817 j, -85.204 - 174.817 j}$$
with \$j\$ as the imaginary unit.

So, can I tell something about the system from these eigenvalues? Like, can I predict the order of the unit-response or impulse response? Does it mean something that the eigenvalues are complex and conjugated?

Comment: A switching regulator has numerous (small) energy storage mechanisms; all these parasitics implement a very high order system; avoiding chaotic behavior becomes your task. I've seen PhDs in SwitchReg not be able to develop a cleanly operating SwitchReg. Beware of the many parasitics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The eigenvalues are the poles of the system.  The number of eigenvalues is the order of the system.  Complex conjugate poles will contribute oscillations to the response.

Comment: And conjugated poles mean an oscillating response.

Comment: Are they ALWAYS the poles of the system? As far as I know, there were a condition about it. If the system satisfies X condition, then the eigenvalues are the poles but I'm not sure, I did read it a time ago..

Comment: All dynamic systems have poles.

Comment: You may wanna check this link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/866939/in-what-cases-are-the-eigenvalue-equal-to-the-pole-points in which eigenvalues versus poles is discussed. By the way, what don't use the PWM switch model to analyze the Cùk converter?